i want to export order data. i want to include wordpress display_name
hye, do anyone know how to export order including with wordpress user display name?
enter image description here
add wordpress user display name when export order .. in the image it show Display name publicly as .. i want this display name to be export with order report im using excel file xls. do anyone know how to do this
ode? i need php code . i already using this code, but still error
$user_id = 672;
$display_name= 'Les Yeux';

$user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $display_name ) );


With the help of the givem code we can extend the order export functionality to include the user's display name, and this code has been added we can go to your WooCommerce orders page and then try exporting the orders. In the exported file we should have the display name.
This code needs to be added to functions.php file of the theme.
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_export_columns', 'add_display_name_to_order_export' );

function add_display_name_to_order_export($columns) {
    $columns['display_name'] = __( 'User Display Name', 'your-text-domain' );
    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_export_row', 'add_display_name_to_order_row', 10, 2 );

function add_display_name_to_order_row($order, $data) {
    // This is to get the user ID from the order.
    $user_id = $order->get_customer_id();

    // This is to get the user's display name.
    $display_name = '';
    if ( $user_id ) {
        $user_info    = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $display_name = $user_info->display_name;
    }

    // This is to add display name to the export row.
    $data['display_name'] = $display_name;

    return $data;
}

